# Android AutoCompleteTextView result in List instead of default dropdown

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

Android AutoCompleteTextView search and returns the result in List instead of default dropdown.

Is there a way that I could redesign and put the result of an AutoCompleteTextView into a list other than to its default list design?

In my MainActivity, I have this:

```
    String[]fruits = {"apple", "avocado", "banana", "blackberry", "blueberry", "coconut", "durian", "mango", "melon"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, fruits);

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocom);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
    autoCompleteTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);

}
```

In My xml,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.autocompletenativesample.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Pick a Fruit"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        />
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/autocom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ListView Implementation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autocom"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
        >

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RecyclerView Implementation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lv"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Furthermore, here is a [Visual Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUI94.png). It will search in AutoCompleteTextView field but the result will not be displayed below instead on another layout.

Should I edit the ArrayAdapter ang change the layout, or have a CustomAutoCompleteTextView that implements AutoCompleteTextView or and EditText that implements AutoCompleteTextView.

I desire for my AutoCompleteTextView's Result to be formatted like this. 
[RecyclerView and CardView Result design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvL9m.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can give you the logic. check out this link. 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/ and this too http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/08/android-filters-for-simple-listview.html

and filteration is done in adapter so first bind listview with your empty adapter and in textWatcher bindlistview with datasource filteration and notifie for changes.